# Firebase Authentication with phoneNumber failed with Internal error

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to use `Firebase` `SMS` `Authentication` with phone number.

I have already enabled push notification in my app setting and registered `Firebase` Apns authentication key as google document says.
However, after I sent phone number with country code, Xcode says,

> Failed to receive remote notification to verify app identity within 5
>   second(s)

Error says as below:

```
    error: Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17999 "An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information." UserInfo={error_name=ERROR_INTERNAL_ERROR, NSLocalizedDescription=An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information., NSUnderlyingError=0x28329c8a0 {Error Domain=FIRAuthInternalErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={FIRAuthErrorUserInfoDeserializedResponseKey={
    code = 500;
    errors =     (
                {
            domain = global;
            message = "Internal error encountered.";
            reason = backendError;
        }
    );
    message = "Internal error encountered.";
    status = INTERNAL;
}}}}
```

My code:

```
    PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, uiDelegate: nil) { verificationId, error in
                if let error = error {
                    print("error: \(error)")
                    return
                }
                print("verificationId: \(verificationId!)")
                UserDefaults.standard.set(verificationId, forKey: "authVerificationID")
                self.goToSecondVC()
            }
```

Any idea??

Comment: `APNS` certs uploaded on firebase?

Comment: @DharmeshKheni  On setting/Cloud Messaging tab, it seems that users can choose to upload either APNs Auth key or APNs cert.  Since I uploaded APNs Auth key, I suppose I do not have to upload APNs cert...